# Angularfire multiple upload

Tags: angularfire2

I want to upload few images and I have code as below. It returns the download link, but for only one image. How can I get a list of links to uploaded images?

```js
  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, public afs: AngularFirestore, ) {
    this.files = this.afs.collection('files').valueChanges();
  }

  uploadFile(event) {
    // reset the array 
    this.uploads = [];
    const filelist = event.target.files;
    const allPercentage: Observable<number>[] = [];

    for (const file of filelist) {
      const filePath = `${file.name}`;
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
      const _percentage$ = task.percentageChanges();
      allPercentage.push(_percentage$);

      // observe percentage changes
      this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

      // get notified when the download URL is available
      task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        })
      ).subscribe();
      // this.downloadURLs.push(this.downloadURL);
    }
  }
```

```js
uploadFile(files) {
    //console.log(this.uploadService.uploadFile(file));
    this.uploadService.uploadFile(files);
  }
```

```html
<ion-item>
      <ion-input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)" multiple="multiple"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    
    <button (click)="onAddItem()" ion-button block>Добавить</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way: Clear `this.downloadURLs` before uploaded, then add url in `finalize` step

```js
uploadFile(event) {
    // reset the array 
    this.uploads = [];
    this.downloadURLs = [];
    const filelist = event.target.files;
    const allPercentage: Observable<number>[] = [];

    for (const file of filelist) {
      const filePath = `${file.name}`;
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
      const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
      const _percentage$ = task.percentageChanges();
      allPercentage.push(_percentage$);

      // observe percentage changes
      this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

      // get notified when the download URL is available
      task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => { 
            this.downloadURLs = this.downloadURLs.concat([url]);
          });
        })
      ).subscribe();
      // this.downloadURLs.push(this.downloadURL);
    }
  }
```

Rxjs way: First combine all latest result, then subscribe to assign results. Note: You can use `forkJoin` too

```js
   import { combineLatest, from } from 'rxjs';
   import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

   ...

      uploadFile(event) {
        // reset the array 
        this.uploads = [];
        const filelist = event.target.files;
        const allPercentage: Observable<number>[] = [];
        const downloadUrls$ = filelist.map((file) => {

          const filePath = `${file.name}`;
          const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
          const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
          const _percentage$ = task.percentageChanges();
          allPercentage.push(_percentage$);

          // observe percentage changes
          this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();

          // get notified when the download URL is available
          return task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            filter((task) => task.state === this.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS)
            switchMap(() => from(fileRef.getDownloadURL()))
          )
        });

        combineLatest(...downloadUrls$)
          .subscribe((urls) => this.downloadURLs = urls)
      }
```

Comment: First one works for me, but how can I properly display it on the view? Remember I'm calling upload function via service.

Comment: You mean showing download URLs? Just use `downloadURLs` property in template. it will show in UI

Comment: Yes, I mean in template. I did it, but it returns [object Object]

Comment: Sorry, I read the doc. `getDownloadURL` return `Promise`. I fixed the code.

Comment: Worked, thanks. I also updated .then with .subscribe to make it compilable and working.

Comment: I tried to follow the rjxs code template but the combineLatest is not invoked. Probably I believe there is change in API